# How can I read and write text into a jpg header using PHP?

Tags: php, jpeg

I know this works with Photoshop where you can insert all kinds of text that serves a copyright.

Is it possible with PHP? How would you go about doing it?

**UPDATE**

I am talking about meta data in the file header, not a watermark.

For example, I'n Photoshop when you open a file you can click on File-> File info.. and set Document title, descriptions, keywords .... all the way to IPTC.

Comment: Something like this maybe? : http://phpimageworkshop.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [PHP Exif Library](http://pel.sourceforge.net/) is what you want:

> The PHP Exif Library (PEL) lets you
>   fully manipulate Exif (Exchangeable
>   Image File Format) data. This is the
>   data that digital cameras place in
>   their images, such as the date and
>   time, shutter speed, ISO value and so
>   on.
>
> Using PEL, one can fully modify the
>   Exif data, meaning that it can be both
>   read and written. Completely new Exif
>   data can also be added to images. PEL
>   is written completely in PHP and
>   depends on nothing except a standard
>   installation of PHP, version 5. PEL is
>   hosted on SourceForge.

Comment: I think he means something more akin to watermarking the image, rather than metadata. But it is a little vague.

Comment: I'm sorry if its vague, I meant it quite literally. Amal is closest to what I mean, I will try and elaborate a bit..